# React-router-v6 cannot get page on refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have routes like this

```
import React from "react"
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
...

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
          <div className="content">
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects/>} />
              <Route path="/projects/:id" element={<ProjectsDetails/>}/>
              <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I can navigate this routes without any problem. If I refresh page on "**/projects**", is also not a problem.

I can navigate "**/projects/1**" without any problem. But If I refresh page in there, I get an error "GET http://localhost:9200/projects/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)"

There is no problem in main routes but it is problem in url with params (when page refresh).

How can I solve this?

**Edit**

```
 webpack.config

    ...
    devServer: 
   {
            port: 9200,
            contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "/dist"),
            hot: true,
            watchContentBase: true,
            historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    ...
```

[**Live on CodeSandBox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/black-tree-kf24bg?file=/src/pages/projects.js)

I did not encounter any problems in the demo here. It seems the problem is in my config.

**Solution**

With Валера Битковский's suggestion, I added

```
<base href="/">
```

in index.html file.

Comment: Seems it isn't react-router problem. Looks like you have some error into your ProjectsDetails component and this logic breaks when you update page. Check your project console, maybe you have some problems there

Comment: This is an issue with how the app is being served up. How are you running the app locally?

Comment: Check your webpack config. It appears it’s using relative paths to load the JavaScript but it always assumes that the visitor is at the root directory of the site

Comment: @ВалераБитковский There is no error in ProjectsDetails component. It is just return <div>Hello</div>. If that were the case, I would have had problems with the first redirect as well. The problem is occur when I reload the page.

Comment: @DrewReese I run app locally and  use Node.Js/Express.Js as backend. I know the "Cannot Get" problem in react-router. I took the necessary precautions. Anyway, the problem does not occur on the main routes (/projects), but on the ones with parameters.(/projects/:id)

Comment: @AbirTaheer I added webpack config to post.

Comment: @BK52 try to add <base href="/"> or even better <base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/"> to your index.html into the head tag

Comment: @ВалераБитковский, If you add this solution as an answer I can accept it and the topic will be closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems your app is trying to get bundle from wrong path.
Try to add `<base href="/">` or even better `<base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/">` to your index.html into the head tag

Comment: Hi , wondering why this works?Could you give me some explanations?Thx

Comment: @CHIU TZE CHEUNG, The fact is that when the application loads assets, it uses relative paths, that is, let's say you have a page at example.com/projects, in this case it will try to load them again at a relative path, that is, with the /projects prefix, since the application itself does not know anything about where the assets are stored, in this case we can explicitly indicate the exact path in each asset's src in index.html or add the base tag, which in fact indicates from which link to the assets should be built

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am using react router with express and couldn't get sub pages to render on refresh. This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using express,  I added this to my index.js file on the server:

```
app.use(express.static('build'))

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './build/index.html'));
});
```

What's actually happening?

1. When the user first goes to the site homepage, `app.use` serves the index.html file.
2. When the user navigates around the site, it is completely local to their computer, since it is a Single Page App and they have all the pages they need (you can test this by switching off your wifi).
3. When the browser refreshes a page that is NOT the homepage, like `/faq`, it talks to the server, asking it to give `/faq`.
4. Server says I don't have this page! I only have `/` homepage.
5. The fix is to add a catch all, to give the SPA again, and the browser will append the link `/faq` to it.